# How can I fix the CSRF-AjaxFail error when trying to sign in to a website using Python requests and Ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, python-requests

iam try to sign in website, this is my code:

```
session = requests.Session()

gt_hm = session.get('https://www.worldmarket.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(gt_hm.text, 'html.parser')
csrf_token = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrf_token'})['value']

hd_lg = {
    'Cookie': 'dwac_0a0c391a8512460c68e85228bc=vuUazbyOaIIg6ibmhgl-wnjzW4TwmaTedTc%3D|dw-only|||USD|false|America%2FLos%5FAngeles|true; cqcid=acjv9TWwTJ1tXpYzR0vabxdC9J; cquid=||; sid=vuUazbyOaIIg6ibmhgl-wnjzW4TwmaTedTc; dwanonymous_43647d49384023dce43a2925f808b1ce=acjv9TWwTJ1tXpYzR0vabxdC9J; __cq_dnt=0; dw_dnt=0; dwsid=-D4Id5Dim_ssmK9m4z19DT4oST7c9VeneUU4GLxVpZHmFElwSSd7Z2NzqVYlaIZwajFBM1mhhLvfE1xcWl-A5A==; AMCV_BE4F210654F6058E0A4C98A7%40AdobeOrg=1176715910%7CMCIDTS%7C19509%7CMCMID%7C19946044664685915239064589652777022263%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1686176867%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1686176867%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CMCCIDH%7C0%7CMCOPTOUT-1685579267s%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-19516%7CvVersion%7C5.4.0; crl8.fpcuid=31acfbf1-b9b4-4e58-931c-bac727c42e78; __cq_uuid=acjv9TWwTJ1tXpYzR0vabxdC9J; __cq_seg=0~0.00!1~0.00!2~0.00!3~0.00!4~0.00!5~0.00!6~0.00!7~0.00!8~0.00!9~0.00; liveagent_oref=; liveagent_vc=2; mp_world_market_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2218873ec919c88-0d7bf858bd2c6d8-d565429-144000-18873ec919d2ab%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201685572068056%2C%22bc_id%22%3A%201452614070%7D; _uetsid=5c982510000211ee9ce4fd7311459456; _uetvid=5c986330000211eeba89c7bfabd286bc; _gcl_au=1.1.729482617.1685572064; _ga_JCP1JBMS87=GS1.1.1685572064.1.0.1685572064.60.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.94765653.1685572064; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU9EVTNZalZrT1RFdFpHWXlOQzAwWVdKbUxUZzNObVF0WWpaaE0yUmlObUl3TVdRMQ; _gid=GA1.2.213691384.1685572065; liveagent_sid=4c12ad12-f13c-457e-874c-5ee1b9e0573a; liveagent_ptid=4c12ad12-f13c-457e-874c-5ee1b9e0573a; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=DwdasJeT9_5NRr4--U5ZONCKAs-; _fbp=fb.1.1685572065630.660571316; AMCVS_BE4F210654F6058E0A4C98A7%40AdobeOrg=1; s_vnum=1688158800679%26vn%3D1; s_invisit=true; pvv=1; c24=cpwm%3Ahome_page; s_cmdl=1; s_cm=Typed%2FBookmarkedTyped%2FBookmarkedundefined; v7=%5B%5B%27Direct%27%2C%271685572067682%27%5D%5D; v4=Direct; s_sq=mlcpwmproduction%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253Dcpwm%25253Ahome_page%2526link%253DSIGN%252520IN%2526region%253Dregistered-customer%2526pageIDType%253D1%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253Dcpwm%25253Ahome_page%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253DSIGN%252520IN%2526oidt%253D3%2526ot%253DSUBMIT; s_cc=true; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9S1JZaFBHdW04ZUVXVl9zaC1aSDZkMEs2b1d5Z2JwUGwmbj1DSmk1eTJldlRLb08wSGoyWlQ4ZVJBJm09MTAmdD1BQUFBQUdSM3llVSZybT0xMCZydD1BQUFBQUdSM3llVSZzcD0x',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Length': '909',
    'Origin': 'https://www.worldmarket.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.worldmarket.com/?rurl=1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Te': 'trailers'
}

while True:
    captcha_value = solveCpatcha(final_api)
    if captcha_value == "CAPCHA_NOT_READY":
        print("not ready")
    else:
        break
dt_lg = {
    'dwfrm_coRegisteredCustomer_email': 'myEmaill@gmail.com',
    'dwfrm_coRegisteredCustomer_password': 'MyPassword**',
    'csrf_token': csrf_token,
    'wishlistProductId': '',
    'gRecaptchaResponse': str(captcha_value)
}
url = "https://www.worldmarket.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-World_Market-Site/en_US/Account-Login?rurl=1"
#dt_lg = 'dwfrm_coRegisteredCustomer_email=myEmaill%40gmail.com&dwfrm_coRegisteredCustomer_password=mypassword!!!@##**&csrf_token='+csrf_token+'&wishlistProductId=&gRecaptchaResponse='+captcha_value
pst_lg = session.post(url, headers=hd_lg, data=json.dumps(dt_lg))
print(pst_lg.text)
```

but the response is:

```
{
  "action": "CSRF-AjaxFail",
  "queryString": "",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "csrfError": true,
  "redirectUrl": "/on/demandware.store/Sites-World_Market-Site/en_US/CSRF-Fail"
}
```

iam get the csrf from the page source, but why this error ?! how i can fix it ?

iam try send data used json dumps, and send us header but the problem is same !